# When should vpc be set on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

I have a general question, but it's important. Often in the tips I see options to set up an instance or install something using VPC. I also often read that it is related to server security, access etc. However, I do not know exactly when and how to set it properly and when it is important ? Isn't ordinary procedures like firewall on the server and blocked shh port for selected IPs enough? Is VPC really important ?

Where should i start in order to properly understand if i needs to be interested in it, e.g. when a website / portal will become more popular and thus more vulnerable to attacks from the network ?

Or maybe apart from the VPC, there are other things to be considered ? And do the same rules also apply to Lightsail ? Because there (perhaps) many things can't be changed (or maybe it's better for a beginner?).

Answer (score 1):

**Connectivity**

**A VPC is a network.** For example, if you setup a new PC at home, you will connect the computer to your network router. However, your neighbour is *not* allowed to plug into your router. Thus, you are making a network that you control, but you don't want other people on your network. That 'network' is a VPC.

Companies often have **multiple networks**: One for dev/test, a separate one for production (so data doesn't actually leak, or to prevent developers from overwriting production systems), perhaps a different one for HR (to ensure privacy), and probably a different one for security cameras. Each of these can be a separate VPC.

Put simply, **computers can talk to each other if they are on the same VPC**. If they are on a separate VPC, they (normally) can't talk to each other, just like your home computer can't talk directly to your neighbour's computer. Since most modern applications run across multiple computers, they all need to connect to the same VPC to communicate with each other.

**Security**

You are correct that VPCs can also be used for security. By default, a VPC has no connectivity to the Internet. Once an Internet Gateway is added to a VPC, resources can be exposed to the Internet. This is potentially dangerous, so additional security controls are provided such as **Security Groups** (which limits which ports are accessible to which IP addresses), **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) (which limit network traffic can traverse subnets) and the concept of a **private subnet** (that ensures no connectivity with the Internet). All these elements reside *inside* a VPC.

**Default VPC**

When new users join AWS, they typically want to launch an Amazon EC2 instance and start playing with the service. If this required that they first configure a VPC, many users would give up in frustration. Therefore, AWS provides a **default VPC** in each region. This default VPC contains subnets in each Availability Zone and allows new users to immediately launch resources (eg EC2, RDS) in a VPC.

However, once they start to understand how to use AWS, it is recommended that they create their own VPCs and possibly even delete the Default VPC.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the last point. What's wrong with a typical default automatic vpc for EC2 or other tools like Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

> When and how to set it properly and when it is important ?

Always. You always have a VPC if you use VM in AWS

> Isn't ordinary procedures like firewall on the server and blocked shh
> port for selected IPs enough?

There is a lot of best practices, and they depends on your app, your risks, the threats... AWS VPC provides multiples layer of firewalls to configure (NACL and Security Group)

> Is VPC really important ?

As said before, you cannot launch an EC2 without a VPC.

> Or maybe apart from the VPC, there are other things to be considered ?

If you only need EC2 then just the basics about NACL, Security group and IAM.

> And do the same rules also apply to Lightsail ?

You don't manage the VPC in Lightsail.

**My advice :** You seem lost with all the AWS features, and if you consider Lightsail, then you should go for it or another cloud provider. No need to manage all these features if you don't understand them, and don't see the usefulness.

Comment: ad. Your advice. What's wrong with Lightsail that you're advising me on another provider? Which one would be better and why?

Comment: There is no problem with Lightsail, nor advantage for it compare to other PaaS you can find on any provider in my opinion.